# How to add tokens (UIControl) to a UITextField or SearchBar programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicontrol

How to add tokens (UIControl) to a UITextField or SearchBar programmatically without another library?

Similar to the way Gmail adds contacts or iOS Mail tokenizes names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextField's have `leftView` and `rightView` properties that you can use to insert something into the text field. It's good for little icons (like a key icon in password box) but you can literally put anything you'd like here. For tokenizing names, I'd just create an UIView and add a label programatically with intials or something and set it as `leftView` of the field.

Comment: This seems to work great especially with leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always thank you

Comment: can anyone refer to library like this?